# What does "The resulting stream is ordered if both of the input streams are ordered" mean in the Javadoc?

Tags: java, java-stream

The Javadoc of the Stream::concat-method says:

> The resulting stream is ordered if both of the input streams are
> ordered

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#concat(java.util.stream.Stream,java.util.stream.Stream)

What does that mean?

Having

```
Stream<Integer> s1 = Stream.of(1,3,5,7); // ordered
Stream<Integer> s2 = Stream.of(2,4,6,8); // ordered
Stream<Integer> s = Stream.concat(s1, s2); // not ordered!
s.forEach(System.out::println);
```

the output is:

```
1
3
5
7
2
4
6
8
```

i.e. the concatenated stream is not ordered. So what does the cited part mean?

Comment: you are thinking of "sorting".  "ordering" refers to the encounter order of the stream.  there are a ton of resources online which explain this, here's a quick link https://www.baeldung.com/java-stream-ordering

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is still ordered. The first stream's elements were printed and then the seconds.  It appears you are confusing `sorted` with `ordered`. You get the same result when using `s.forEachOrdered(System.out::println)`.

```
Stream<Integer> s1 = Stream.of(1,3,5,7); // ordered
Stream<Integer> s2 = Stream.of(2,4,6,8); // ordered
Stream<Integer> s = Stream.concat(s1, s2); // not ordered!
s.forEachOrdered(System.out::println);
```

prints

```
1
3
5
7
2
4
6
8
```